# iPhone is it possible to have a shortened version of the app name for the home screen?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I noticed that most of the labels on the iPhone4 retina display home screen are about 10 letters or less. App names longer than that get truncated in the middle. So if I name my app Alex's App, it will display in full, but if I name it Alex's Fantastically Awesome app, the name would appear as something like  Ale...ome App.

**Is it possible to declare the "display" name of the app for the home screen which is different from the name used to list the app on the app store? Kind of like a nick name?** Is there some sort of property in my Xcode project that controls this?

Comment: Thats not project related, thats iTunes related. I know that there is an iTunesMetadata.plist that is downloaded with the app that contains the store display name, but I unfortunately don't know how to set that.

Comment: I never thought about it, good! :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can change the name of your app that will be displayed in the Info.plist file of your project, by using the `Bundle display name` key.

This is the name that will be displayed on the Springboard below the app icon, regardless of how you name your app in ItunesConnect.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I've been looking for!

Answer (score 3):

Open up the `InfoPlist.strings` file inside your Xcode project, and add the following:

```
"CFBundleDisplayName~ipad" = "My Long App Name"; // eg, for iPad/retina
"CFBundleDisplayName" = "My App"; // eg, for non-retina
```